# Triying to configure phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using Apache and PHP 5.4.35 on a windows 7 pc. When trying to configure phpMyAdmin, i edited my httpd.conf file (DirectoryIndex index.html to DirectoryIndex index.php). When tried loading localhost/phpmyadmin i get the following:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';
```

This goes on.

From what i´ve found online, i guess i must be trapped between steps 7 and 8 of the explanations provided in http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php (although im on windows 7)

The thing is i think i need to add the following statement,

LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

pointing to the corresponding file in c:/php/ folder, but i don´t know which file should it be.

I don´t sound too technical ´cause i am a total newbie to this,

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Wrong OS, as your a beginner why not use one of the umteen million WAMP packages out there (do a search), which include phpmyadmin

Comment: I read packages gave more problems in the long run. Also i prefer going in the hard way.

Comment: I would recommend using an application over phpMyAdmin, such as HeidiSQL, because I feel that a web based database manager is more insecure... That is just my opinion though.

Comment: vs not being able to get going in the short term... makes sense.. download the most common WAMP, learn how its setup and configured, work your way through all the nuts an bolts, then go ahead and build your own.

Comment: Personally I like Adminer, but who cares ;p

Comment: @ Loz Cherone i don´t see how any of your answers is relevant to my question.